# React/redux toolkit fetchapi issue -- I am trying to get userlist and its showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

in below react/ redux toolkit app , in userslice file I am trying to export my entities piece of state and import in main file , when I try to console in comes undefined , not sure why its undefined ,
but When I trying to pull the {entities} directly form state its working fine, would like to know why its showing undefined in console, if anyone knows please check ?

below is the state part which I am getting undefined

**export const { SelectUserList } = (state) => state.userslist.entities;**

---

below is the console which shows undefiend

```
  console.log(SelectUserList);
```

my slice file is below

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchuserlist = createAsyncThunk(
  "userslist/fetchusers",
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const users = await response.json();
    return users;
  }
);
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userslist",
  initialState: {
    entities: [],
    loading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    // userAdded(state, action) {
    //   state.entities.push(action.payload);
    // },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchuserlist.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [fetchuserlist.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.entities = [...state.entities, ...action.payload];
      state.loading = false;
    },
    [fetchuserlist.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { userAdded, userUpdated, userDeleted } = userSlice.actions;
export const { SelectUserList } = (state) => state.userslist.entities;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

me component file is below

```
import React from "react";
import { fetchuserlist, SelectUserList } from "./features/userSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
const Mainlist = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { entities } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  console.log(SelectUserList);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchuserlist())}>Load list</button>
      {entities?.map((s) => (
        <div className="user_list" key={s.id}>
          <h4>{s.id}</h4>
          <h6>{s.email}</h6>
          <button>delete</button>
          <button>edit</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mainlist;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your slice you are declaring the function in the wrong way. You should declare the SelectUserList function like this:

```
export const SelectUserList = (state) => state.userslist.entities;
```

In your component file you should access the entities returned in `SelectUserList` with a `useSelector`. Like this:

```
const usersListEntities = useSelector(SelectUserList);
```